# How to prevent Sympy printing the negative term first

Tags: python, sympy

`sympy` prints some expressions putting the negative term first.

example:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Matrix
import numpy as np
m = 3

obj = np.dtype(object)
ρ = np.asarray([symbols(f"ρ_{i}") for i in range(m)], obj)
ε = np.asarray([symbols(f"ε_{i}") for i in range(m)], obj)


expr = ε - ρ * ε[1]
    
Matrix(expr)
```

output:

[image]

Here, I want second and third elements to be printed as the first element (positive term comes first), is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can try is:

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
init_printing(order="none")
```

then:

```
m = 3
obj = np.dtype(object)
ρ = np.asarray([symbols(f"ρ_{i}") for i in range(m)], obj)
ε = np.asarray([symbols(f"ε_{i}") for i in range(m)], obj)
expr = ε - ρ * ε[1]
    
Matrix(expr)
```

[image]